# Почему сообщение в логах неправильно отображается?

Tags: laravel

Почему в логах сообщение, которое отправляется на почту, выглядит так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверное не стоит Content-type заголовок)

Comment: Смотрите `Content-Transfer-Encoding` - он определяет способ представления символов. У вас там `quoted-printable`. Хотите base64 - ищите способ для `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. Хотите видеть русские буквы? Не получится, не по стандарту MIME. Вот [объяснение](https://sigparser.com/developers/email-parsing/parse-raw-email/).